# JAVA APIs to modify postgres parameters : GCP Postgres

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql

Our organisation is planning to migrate to GCP Postgres from on-premise. Currently, we have a JAVA program that modifies the config parameters of Postgres. I understand that CloudSQL provides a CLI tool to modify or automate the modification of DB parameters. However are there any APIs which we can call from the JAVA program to modify the parameters?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cloud SQL Admin API to administrate with Cloud SQL instances. There are [Client Libraries for many languages, including Java](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/libraries#java).